# How do you deal with other people’s messy, substandard code on a new job?

Tags: php, frameworks, coding-style

This is a general coding question so please feel free to answer any way that is applicable to you.

When I work on new development for clients that I freelance for I write frameworks, write all the front and backend code and everything is just great.

On numerous occasions, I’ve been brought in as a contractor and sat down on day one to try and do what I’ve been asked and been frustrated, terrified and mystified at past work others have done before me. The boss always expects fast results but I feel like I need a week or two just to really get up to speed on everything going on with these complex and slopily written "frameworks" that have been done before me.  Is this normal?  If so, how do you PHP developers deal with this challenge?

Comment: This is worth a read: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/455271

Comment: I read it but I don’t feel like it’s exactly applicable to my situation. My situation is more "this doesn’t make any sense to me as written, how can I go forward using it when I don’t understand it?"

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is not about a specific programming problem, but rather about a work environment which involves programming. You may be interested in [Workplace.SE](http://workplace.stackexchange.com).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Buddy,

I am currently in the same situation. Just to avoid being all 'Zen' - we have a job to do - lets get it done and move on to the next job.

Aim to meet your goals - get the new functionality working and just let the employer know the code stinks and that you would recommend he gets that sorted out asap. Raise the red flag  and let it go. You know that you have done your job.

Comment: I get this, but the code I’m writing depends on the frameworks that are already in place. How do you deal with depending on someone else’s work and still timely get yours done?

Comment: Its crap --- thats why you feel bad ! Bite down , get the job done and move on. Some programmers are just totally irresponsible. The employer ( most probably a non techie ) just wants things 'working'. He will only appreciate your opinion when you get things to 'work'. Forget clean code, speedy code, etc. Make it work first and then raise a red flag and move on. At least your conscience will not bite.  Do the job and move on buddy ... We are in your corner !